# Content types drop down list and creating a <Please Select> option

Tags: document-library, content-type, file-upload, dropdown

When uploading a new document to a library, I have a list of 10 content types to choose from. However, I am worried that end users will not bother sensibly picking from the list and just pick the default.

This is an issue because each content type has a different retention period, so for legal issues, putting some thought into picking the correct content type is very important.

So I am asking, is there a way to add a  option as the default so that the user cannot progress until they have chosen from the list?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is, create a custom drop down list and add all you content types there. You can set validations too using PreSaveAction.

When user selects the drop down you can trigger change event and set the value in the actual content type dropdown (which will be hidden for users)